# Checkbox required not validating

Tags: infopath, validation

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045235/infopath-2010-validate-i-agree-checkbox-before-submitting you can set a checkbox to "required" and it will validate that they have to check it before submitting the form.

But when I set this up, it does not require it to be checked. Is there something I'm missing, or is that first sentence in the answer just inaccurate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think the first sentence there is inaccurate.  Later in the answer he says:

> If required doesn't cut it, just add a validation to the checkbox, so
>   it needs to be `true`.

which logically makes sense: even though you are setting the checkbox to be "required" and have your validation as "cannot be blank", *either state of the checkbox (checked or cleared) results in a valid value (true or false)*.  A cleared checkbox is not equivalent to "does not have value."

So you need to add extra validation to only allow `true` as the only valid value.

Comment: https://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/

Answer (score 0):

The 'Cannot be blank' option works great if you set the 'Value when cleared' option to (blank) instead of FALSE.

[image: Check Box Properties]